# Are there any truly display independent units for placing things on android canvas/screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, wear-os

I'm developing a watch face for wear os. I was trying to figure out why the layout is messed up on different screen sizes and resolutions - I was using "dp" for all dimensions so I thought it will be "density independent", yes?
I made few emulators with different dpi and sizes and could not figure out why bigger change id dpi makes my layout look good again, but smaller changes introduce offset. I found out that:

> One note about dp/sp that isn't totally obvious: The scaling that occurs for these depends not on the devices real density (dpi) but on which "bucket" of densities it falls into: available buckets are: 120,160,240,320. (...)
>
> Note that pt should give you equivalent results as dp

So are there any truly display independent(proportional to screen) units I can use to position my elements?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make decision Y?" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow. Only Developer X is likely to be able to provide a definitive answer. Unless the reason for that decision is documented somewhere, anyone else would only be able to offer opinions. My guess is that they wanted `dp` units to line up with `drawable`/`mipmap` resource set density qualifiers, which are also based on the buckets. Note that `pt` should give you equivalent results as `dp`, in that both will be using the density buckets.

Comment: I agree, the question is more "what is a correct way of using it?" And now , when you said that pt behaves the same - is there any way of getting truly display independent units? I can use grid like `float pixel_grid = screen_width / 160` and use that as a basis for placing things on canvas.
I have "ui borders etc" on background bitmap and I'm aligning elements to that.
Scaled bitmap in `onSurfaceChanged` `float scale = ((float) screen_width) / (float) mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth();`

Comment: I ended up setting offsets and dimensions in px and multiplying it by same scale as the images. It works, but I feel like reinventing the wheel